# building a conversion calculator of ingredients in food

Tags: javascript, html

Need help with building a conversion calculator of weights of ingredients in food
For example: conversion of a cup of sugar to 200 grams

I understand very little about JavaScript, Python is not useful because it is not graphic
I would love to help with that, Even just a basic template and I will continue to build the sequel

Comment: can you state the more specific problem statement please.

Comment: If you're not comfortable with JS yet, check out [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn) for their JavaScript interactive lessons

Comment: Python not graphic? Depends on what you use

Comment: <html>
  <head>
     <title>My First HTML Page With JavaScript Code</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

var cup = 1
var grams = 200
function e(inputCups){
cup = inputCups
grams = cup * 200
return grams
}
            
        </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    The rest of the document....
 </body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

You said you don't know much about JS. You should try [This](https://www.w3schools.com/js/).

Hmm... This may be hard.
How about:
JS:

```
var cup = 1
var grams = 200
function e(inputCups){
cup = inputCups
grams = cup * 200
return grams
}
```

Of course, the 200 would be replaced by the amount of grams in that cup of sugar.
: )
Call the function:

```
e(document.getElementById('/*id of cups input*/'))
```

But more like:

```
document.getElementById('/*id of grams display*/').innerHTML = e(document.getElementById('/*id of cups input*/'))
```

Hope this helped!